# How to create separate DetailTable on each row in a RadGrid?

Tags: telerik, radgrid, radgridview

I have a telerik radgrid where columns and detail tables are declared like:

```
<telerik:RadGrid>
  <Columns>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn/>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn/>
  </Columns>
  <DetailTables>
    <telerik:GridTableView
      <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn/>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn/>
      </Columns>
    </telerik:GridTableView
  </DetailTables>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Which gives a nested grid like this:

[image: nested grid]

Now, what I want is to be able to specify a detail table (those sub tables) per row, programmatically.

(I cannot be sure that the columns for the nested table that comes up when I expand the line fgvbvb will be the same as the columns when expanding the line xcxcv).

I have tried, without luck in the OnDataBound handler of the radgrid (in which I omitted `<DetailTables>`) to access the data structure for nested tables like this:

```
    protected void OnRadGridDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridDataItem item in grdActivitiesToCopy.MasterTableView.Items)
        {
            var dg = item.ChildItem.NestedTableViews[0];

        }
    }
```

This will overindex the array NestedTableViews because it is empty. Also, item.ChildItem.NestedTableViews has no setter.

How do I populate each row with a detail table one by one manually?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, when working with detail tables you do not use the NestedTableViews as that is a different tool. You have DetailTables and NestedTables which cannot access one another. If you just want to add a gridview to each row, then you need a GridTemplateColumn in your radgrid and you can populate the template column grid from the code behind. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

First of all , because of the life cicle of a asp page. You can't access to a event on a detail table.

If you need to access detail tables , items etc ..
You need to add an method to the *PreRender* in the *MasterTableView* like this:

```html
<MasterTableView   DataSourceID="myDataSource"
                   AllowMultiColumnSorting="True" 
                   DataKeyNames="Key1,Key2,KeyN" 
                   HierarchyDefaultExpanded="True"
                   OnPreRender="Unnamed_PreRender" >
```

The method will recursively iterate through the grid.

The way you do it can change depending on your *HieararchyLoadMode*.

So this is my way to do it, easiest way exist if you are on Client or Serverbind mode.

Traversing and load mode by the  [telerik doc](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/hierarchical-grid-types-and-load-modes/traversing-detail-tables) .

I'm pretty sure you don't want to :

> "populate each row with a detail table one by one manually"

You want to have Multiple table at a Sub Level in your grid and display the rigth one programmatically.

And this is can be done in two easy step:

**1/. Create every Detail table in your apsx page.**

Please refer to this documentation for more information :
[Several tables at a level](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/hierarchical-grid-types-and-load-modes/several-tables-at-a-level)

**2/. Handle the display:**

```cs
protected void Unnamed_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack) myControler(MASTERGRID.MasterTableView);
}

 private void myControler(GridTableView gridTableView)
{
    GridItem[] nestedViewItems = gridTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.NestedView);

    foreach (GridNestedViewItem nestedViewItem in nestedViewItems)
    {
        foreach (GridTableView nestedView in nestedViewItem.NestedTableViews)
        {

            if (nestedView.Name == "mytable12" && nestedView.Items.Count == 0)
            { HideExpandColumn(nestedView, nestedView.ParentItem["ExpandColumn"]); }

            else if (nestedView.Name == "mytable23")
            {
                if (nestedView.Items.Count == 0)// 
                    HideExpandColumn(nestedView, nestedView.ParentItem["ExpandColumn"]);
                else
                { }
            }
            if (nestedView.HasDetailTables)
                { myControler(nestedView); }
        }
    }
}

private void HideExpandColumn(GridTableView _GNVI, TableCell _cell)
{
    if (_cell.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        _cell.Controls[0].Visible = false;
        _cell.Text = " ";
    }
    _GNVI.Visible = false;
}
```

You can hide a detail table using :

```cs
HideExpandColumn(nestedView, nestedView.ParentItem["ExpandColumn"]);
```

Or you can hide the parent of the detail table you tested using the detail table that is in param of the controler :

```cs
HideExpandColumn(gridTableView, nestedView.ParentItem["ExpandColumn"]);
```

HideExpandColumn will hide the expand control that stay sometimes even if you hide th detail table.

Bonus: If you need to access to a control in a detail table. 
You can use this:

```cs
public static class ControlExtensions
{
public static Control FindIt(this Control control, string id)
{
    if (control == null) return null;
    Control ctrl = control.FindControl(id);
    if (ctrl == null)
    {
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            ctrl = FindIt(child, id);
            if (ctrl != null) break;
        }
    }
    return ctrl;
}
}
```

Calling it in your controler like this :

```cs
else if (nestedView.Name == "DetailPV")
                {
                    if (nestedView.Items.Count == 0)
                        HideExpandColumn(gridTableView, nestedView.ParentItem["ExpandColumn"]);
                    else
                    {

                        RadLabel ctrl = (RadLabel)this.FindIt("RadLabel11");
                        ctrl.Text += "<b>" + nestedView.Items.Count.ToString() + "</b>";
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Telerik:

> RadGrid does not support mixing declarative grid columns with grid
>   columns added dynamically at runtime. You should either create all the
>   columns in the grid programmatically, or else define them all in the
>   ASPX file. When creating Detail tables, it should be created in the
>   **PageInit** event.

Creating a Hierarchical Grid Programmatically:

> You should follow these basic steps in order to create hierarchical
>   RadGrid programmatically in the code-behind (having a data source
>   control for data content generation):
>
> 1. Create the grid dynamically in the **Page_Init** handler of the page by
>      calling its constructor.
> 2. Specify the preferred settings for your grid instance through its
>      properties.
> 3. Create columns for the grid dynamically. Keep in mind that you have to
>      first set their properties and then add them to the
>      **MasterTableView/GridTableView** collection (discussed in the first
>      paragraph of this same topic). Thus, their **ViewState** will be properly
>      persisted (as **LoadViewState** is raised after the **Init** event of the
>      page).
> 4. Set the proper **ParentTableRelations** for the **GridTableViews** (along with
>      their **MasterKeyField** and **DetailKeyField** attributes) and **DataKeyNames**
>      for the **MasterTableView**/**GridTableViews** in the code-behind of the page.
> 5. Assign data sources (through the DataSourceID attribute) for each
>      table in the grid hierarchy.If you do not want to use declarative
>      relations, generate the data in the **NeedDataSource**/**DetailTableDataBind**
>      handlers of the grid. On **DetailTableDataBind** you can determine which
>      data source should be related to the currently bound **GridTableView** by
>      checking its **Name**/**DataSourceID** property. Here, the **Name** property must
>      have a unique value for each detail table (this value has to be
>      defined previously by the developer) and the **DataSourceID** is the ID of
>      the DataSource control responsible for the corresponding detail table
>      content generation.

Code Sample:

```
    RadGrid RadGrid1 = new RadGrid();
    RadGrid1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "CustomerID" };
    RadGrid1.Skin = "Default";
    RadGrid1.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    RadGrid1.PageSize = 15;
    RadGrid1.AllowPaging = true;
    RadGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    //Add columns
    GridBoundColumn boundColumn;
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "CustomerID";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "CustomerID";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "ContactName";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Contact Name";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    //Detail table - Orders (II in hierarchy level)
    GridTableView tableViewOrders = new GridTableView(RadGrid1);
    tableViewOrders.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource2";
    tableViewOrders.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "OrderID" };
    GridRelationFields relationFields = new GridRelationFields();
    relationFields.MasterKeyField = "CustomerID";
    relationFields.DetailKeyField = "CustomerID";
    tableViewOrders.ParentTableRelation.Add(relationFields);
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DetailTables.Add(tableViewOrders);
```

Please refer to this help article for more details: 
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/defining-structure/creating-a-radgrid-programmatically#creating-a-hierarchical-grid-programmatically

Comment: `According to Telerik: Radgrid do not support both ..` It's a lie. It's an old old lie.