# Telerik Radgrid issue in Asp.Net Webform Application

Tags: telerik-grid

I am using Telerik Radgrid in a Webform application, my browser is IE 11, my dot net framework is 3.5, my Telerik version is 15.401.35, I am trying to color my hierarchical grid different times different ways and I could not do it.

Sometimes I want to color the inside grid and sometimes I am trying to color the outside grid, the problem becomes complicated when there are two inside grids and I am closing one of them, one inside should remain colored and the outside should not, but the algorithm is coloring both inside and outside grid, what should I do?
I want to conditionally color the parent if the nested grid is existed.

Comment: What about a [mcve] with some simple data and a expected result description. But from my understanding you want to conditionaly  color the parent cell if the nested grid, right ?

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/hierarchical-grid-types-and-load-modes/traversing-detail-tables

Comment: "the algorithm is coloring both inside and outside grid, what should I do?" Perhaps show the algo.. And here is a old answer of mine, that include traversing a grid and his nested child, accessing a control somewhere in the chaos of nested grid. But those are just guess please be more specific, precise([ask]) or provide a simple exmple([mcve])

Comment: Thanks, where is the code traversing the nested grid?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39104164/6560478) I forgot to add the link sorry !

Comment: "I want to conditionally color the parent if the nested grid is existed." Well they always exist even if they have no row...

Comment: The link did not help, do you have any other solutions?